# PHP Updatable Variable

Tags: php, html, scope

I am working on a site that has a variable for the current year. This variable is used throughout the website. The variable needs to be manually updated every year in the middle of the summer. I want to allow the admin to update that variable but it seems wasteful to create an entire table for one value.

The site is written in php and so I was wondering, is there anyway to update a variable with PHP through a form or something like that?

Comment: Is that variable hidden from the public? If not, you can probably just store it in a plaintext file.

Comment: True programmers do not update variables each year - they use their programming skills and knowledge to make the variable update itself.

Comment: This makes less and less sense, can't you use at least a silly `date('Y');` function?

Comment: I agree. But the admin's wants to be able to update it themselves because the time varies in which the variable needs to be changed.

Comment: This sounds like a piece of _Rocket Science Design_ I bet with a little thought you could write a function that would return the correct Year required by your system based on the actual date. Then you dont need to mess with any of this manual amendment rubbish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a file to persist the value.

see [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to get a file handle (use the w+ flag)

see [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to write to the file

see [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) to close the file

(or use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead of these three)

then use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the value as saved in the file.

---

Note also that `date("Y")` will give you the current year. it doesn;t really make sense to update something like a date manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign this variable in a separate PHP file, and include it in the main file.

Then you can change that file(and so its assigned value) simply by `file_put_contents()` function.

```
file_put_contents('sth.php', '<?php $var = "some value"; ?>');
```